# Bidirectionnal Bubble Sort in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I need to implement the bidirectional bubble sort in my code.

In other words `in` will go from left to right first carrying the **largest value**.

But when it reaches `out`, it should reverse and go from right to left carrying the **smallest value**.

*I am advised to to implement another `out` index in addition the current one*.

This is what I have so far - just 2 loops. I am guessing I have to combine them somehow?

```
    public void bubbleSort() {
    int out, in; // nElems in my case is 4, because I have 4 elements in my array

    for(out=nElems-1; out>1; out--) // outer loop backward
        for(in=out; in>1; in--) // inner loop backward
            if(a[in] < a[in-1])
                swap(in, in-1);

    for(out=0; out<nElems; out++) // outer loop forward
        for(in=0; in<out; in++) // inner loop forward
            if(a[in] > a[in+1])
                swap(in, in+1);
```

Comment: is this homework?  only asking since I rarely find Bubble sort in practice

Comment: Yes it is SB. Bubble Sort sucks - true story, but I have to get this project done.

Comment: I am guessing I won't get much help on SO if it's a homework assignment? Not even a clue?

Comment: You will get some help (especially clues), but some people won't want to provide code if they get the feeling you're trying to get someone to do your homework for you.  And some would resent that you're trying to hide that it's homework if it is.

Comment: Just to follow-up on cHao's comment, there's a `homework` tag that you should probably use.

Comment: From the man himself: http://max.cs.kzoo.edu/~abrady/java/sorting/BidirBubbleSort.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public void bidirectionalBubbleSort()
    {
       int left = 0, right = a.length-1;
       while (left < right)
       {
          for (int pos = left; pos < right; pos++)
          {
             if (a[pos] > a[pos+1])
                swap(pos, pos+1);
          }
          right--;


          for (int pos = right; pos > left; pos--)
          {
             if (a[pos] < a[pos-1])
               swap(pos, pos-1);
          }
          left++;
       }
   }
```

Comment: This line is causing Array out of bounds exception: if (a[pos] > a[pos+1])

Comment: my bad, I was decrementing left instead of incrementing it

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you split the method up for chunks that you can comprehend, like:

```
public static boolean swap(int[] numbers, int i, int j) {
    int temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
    numbers[j] = temp;
    return true;
}

static boolean leftSide(int[] numbers, int i, int j) {
    boolean swapped = false;
    for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
        if (numbers[k] > numbers[k + 1])
            swapped = swap(numbers, k, k + 1);
    return swapped;
}

static boolean rightSide(int[] numbers, int i, int j) {
    boolean swapped = false;
    for (int k = j; k > i; k--)
        if (numbers[k] < numbers[k - 1])
            swapped = swap(numbers, k, k - 1);
    return swapped;
}

public static void cocktailSort(int[] numbers) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int i = -1;
    int j = numbers.length - 1;

    while (i++ < j && swapped)
        if (swapped = leftSide(numbers, i, j))
            swapped = rightSide(numbers, i, j--);
}
```

And to test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x[] = new int[] { 2, 6, 3, 7, 8, 3, 7, 5, 4 };
    cocktailSort(x);
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(x));
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8]
```

Comment: If you're gonna return the sorted list, then the original list should remain untouched.  Clone it or something, or have the sort method return something else, even nothing.  (If it's void, for example, its modifying the original list should be obvious to anyone with a clue.)

Comment: Thats a good point. Code now updated to accommodate that change.

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean f1 = false, f2 = false;
    outer:
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++)
           for (int j=i; j< arr.length - i -1; j++) {

               if(arr[j] >= arr[j+1]){
                   f1 = true;
                   int t = arr[j];
                   arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                   arr[j+1] = t;
               }

               if(arr[arr.length - j -1] <= arr[arr.length - j - 2]){

                   f2 = true;
                   int t = arr[arr.length - j -2];
                   arr[arr.length - j -2] = arr[arr.length - j -1];
                   arr[arr.length -j -1] = t;
               }

               /**
                * @param k: iterator variable thats prints each pass..(optional)
                */
               for (int k:arr)
                   System.out.print(" "+k);
               System.out.println("    "+i);

               //Ultimate break condition
               if(j == arr.length - j -2 && (!f1 && !f2))
                   break outer;


           }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bidirectional Bubble Sort** using only **2 loops** & **2 index** variables.

```
public void bubbleSort(){
    for(int out=0;out<nElems/2;out++){
        boolean forward = true;
        for (int in = out;in !=(forward ? out-1 : out)
                         ;in = forward ? in + 1 : in - 1)
        {
            if (in == nElems - (out + 1))
                forward = false;
            if (a[forward ? in + 1 : in] < a[forward?in:in-1])
                swap(forward ? in + 1 : in - 1, in);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bidirectional bubble sort, sorting variable: array[]

```
//-------------------------------------------//
//biderctioanal bubble sort - coctail sort
public void bidirBubbleSort(){
    for(int i=1; i<length/2; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<length-i; j++)
            if(array[j]>array[j+1])
                swap(j, j+1);
        for(int j=length-i; j>=i; j--)
            if(array[j]<array[j-1])
                swap(j, j-1);
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------//
//swap 2 elements
public void swap(int index1, int index2){
    int temp=array[index1];
    array[index1]=array[index2];
    array[index2]=temp;
}
//-------------------------------------------//
```

On 10_000 randomly selected elements, standard bubble sorts completes in 410ms and bidirectional bubble sort in 319ms